# extra_subject not appear in the email app of android

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a small app for send email in android. This app have some EditText and open email default app of the android device and show all the dates ready to send.

The problem is that not appear the subject in the email default app of android device.

This is the code:

```
package com.example.tecnomonkey.co;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ayuda extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ayuda); // aqui decimos que esta clase manipula los objetos del activity_saludo.xml




     // Boton Regresar ------------------------------------------------------------------

        Button BtnRegresar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2); // creo la variable de tipo imagebuton para poder interactuar con ella

        BtnRegresar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { // evento clic del boton

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { 

                // al hacer clic se manda para la otra pagina


                Intent intent = new Intent (ayuda.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);             
                startActivity(intent);

                //---------------------------------------------


            }
        });

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------


        // Boton Enviar Email, el cual abre la aplicacion de email instalada en el cel android

        Button btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                EditText etNombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                EditText etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                EditText etTelefono = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                EditText etCom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);


            // Concateno la info para enviarla

                String c = "Nombre: " + etNombre.getText() + "\n\n" + "Email: " + etEmail.getText() + "\n\n" + "Telefono: " + etTelefono.getText() + "\n\n" + "Problema: " + etCom.getText();

            //----------------------------------


             // es necesario un intent que levante la actividad deseada 
                Intent itSend = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                // vamos a enviar texto plano a menos que el checkbox esté marcado 
                itSend.setType("plain/text");

             // colocamos los datos para el envío 
                itSend.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ "jgomez@rgit.co"});

                itSend.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, c);
                itSend.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, new String[]{ "Ayuda APP Android"});

                startActivity(itSend);

            }
    });

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------




    }
}
```

Any suggestions on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
itSend.setType("plain/text");
```

whith

```
itSend.setType("text/plain");
```

Also, you may send a String as a subject.

```
itSend.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Ayuda APP Android");
```

Comment: what is the different ?

Comment: i change it but don't work.. is the same, not appear the subject