# EXTRA_SUBJECT not getting data

Tags: android, email

I'm trying to send an Email via an Android App. Currently using Android Studio 1.2 and testing on Genymotion 2.4.0 on a Galaxy Nexus 4.3(API 18) image with ARM Translation and Google apps installed. I know this question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069802/extra-subject-not-appear-in-the-email-app-of-android), but I've tried every suggestion there to no effect.

I can retrieve the email(where to send) and the "body" of the email, but unnable to get the email Subject. Code is as follows:

```
Intent iEmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", "email@somewhere.com", null));
iEmail.setType("text/plain");
// Both these "options" don't work
iEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, etTema.getText());
iEmail.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
// This works fine
iEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, etDesc.getText());
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(iEmail, "Choose:"));
```

When the Activity starts and I choose the email client email(to send to) is displayed correctly as is the "body" but the subject remains blank.

EDIT: result is always the same whether i use the EditText(etTema) or try passing a string.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, but I remember using:

```
String uriText = "mailto:youremail@gmail.com" + 
    "?subject=" + Uri.encode("some subject text here") + 
    "&body=" + Uri.encode("some text here");
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriText);
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
sendIntent.setData(uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send email"));
```

See if that works better across devices / APIs for you.

Comment: Tried it but still can't get the "subject" info. Thanks anyway @shkschneider

Answer (score 0):

Try just doing this. This works great for me.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", "email@somewhere.com", null));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, etDesc.getText());
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Email"));
```

Comment: This was how i tried the first time(without "setType"). "subject" is still empty.